Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:dotnet-isolated error happening locally upgrading to .net 8 isolated
I am trying to upgrade my azure function project from .net 6 to .net 8 isolated and it seems there is something wrong with my local because I get the same error in the projects that I developed myself and deployed to production. Here is the full log of what I get: I have also attached an image of the console output.
Starting worker process with FileName:
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe WorkingDirectory:C:\Users\LCK3SNS\source\repos\gcs-gcs-app\Hive.Azure.Functions\bin\Debug\net8.0 Arguments: "C:\Users\LCK3SNS\source\repos\gcs-gcs-app\Hive.Azure.Functions\bin\Debug\net8.0\Hive.Azure.Functions.dll" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 50616 --workerId acfc8109-5970-40a0-9703-c1ccd5d49630 --requestId 67f55fc8-9726-4c85-9322-fb7670094c46 --grpcMaxMessageLength 2147483647 --functions-uri http://127.0.0.1:50616/ --functions-worker-id acfc8109-5970-40a0-9703-c1ccd5d49630 --functions-request-id 67f55fc8-9726-4c85-9322-fb7670094c46 --functions-grpc-max-message-length 2147483647
[2024-07-14T01:53:56.732Z] C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe process with Id=29220 started
[2024-07-14T01:53:56.973Z] Process 29220 has exited with code -2147450730.
[2024-07-14T01:53:56.980Z] Language Worker Process exited. Pid=29220.
[2024-07-14T01:53:56.983Z] C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exited with code -2147450730 (0x80008096). https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed.
[2024-07-14T01:53:56.991Z] Handling WorkerErrorEvent for runtime:dotnet-isolated, workerId:dotnet-isolated. Failed with: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.WorkerProcessExitException: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exited with code -2147450730 (0x80008096)
[2024-07-14T01:53:56.995Z]  ---> System.Exception: https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
[2024-07-14T01:53:56.997Z]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2024-07-14T01:53:57.003Z] Attempting to dispose webhost or jobhost channel for workerId: 'acfc8109-5970-40a0-9703-c1ccd5d49630', runtime: 'dotnet-isolated'
[2024-07-14T01:53:57.020Z] No initialized worker channels for runtime 'dotnet-isolated'. Delaying future invocations
[2024-07-14T01:53:57.024Z] Restarting worker channel for runtime: 'dotnet-isolated'
[2024-07-14T01:53:57.030Z] Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:dotnet-isolated. Shutting down and proactively recycling the Functions Host to recover

I get the same exact error even when I create a test azure function project in .net 8 isolated. And as I said it also happens to the project which I could run fine earlier (which I developed and deployed to production) but not now. Is it because I have some open connections somewhere which the workers don't like? Or any application installed which is exhausting the processes? I have connections to postgresql databases locally.
I uninstalled azure function core tools and downloaded the zip from the official site and added its extracted path to my environment variables, I cleared my visual studio cache and rebuild the project, I restarted my PC too. Nothing just works, am hopeless now
enter image description here

Check if below solution helps to resolve the issue.

Upgrade the packages to the latest version and make sure the versions are compatible with .NET 8.0 isolated.
It could be due to the database connection issue as mentioned in GitHub issue.

Set the Target Framework to.NET 8.0 and FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME:dotnet-isolated.
Delete the AzureFunctionsTools folder under C:\Users\uname\AppData\Local and restart the visual studio again.

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}

Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();


Thanks for the answer. After 3 days of wasting time simply updating visual studio solved the issue
